# Changing folder name with htaccess and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Working with a website that has a large quantity of hard coded pages. The problem is I've been requested to create duplicates of this site with different logos/contacts/addresses. So my thinking was to create URL with the location in it. This location in URL would then be "read" causing the PHP to make changes to specific details.

So URLs would look like:
www.domain.com/repairs-LOCATION/any file

Where as the actual path on the server would be:
www.domain.com/repairs/any file

Complete novice when it comes to htaccess and regular expressions. Initially I tried this, attaching the location name to a file:

```
# Rewrite repairs page URLs
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^repairs/([^\.]+)-repairs?$ repairs/index.php?in=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^repairs repairs/index.php [L]
```

But this was restrictive as ALL calls to the repairs folder were redirected to index.php, so thought renaming the folder would be a better way forward as a user would be able to navigate to other files within the directory.

Tried a redirect, but that defeated the object as the location was removed from the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^repairs-townname/(.*)$ /repairs/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Lastly tried re-jigging the initial attempt, but with no joy.

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^repairs-([^\.]+)/?$ repairs/?in=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

At the moment though struggling to find a solution.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: you don't really need rewrites for this. if each of these "duplicate" sites is being served from a different hostname, then you can simply have PHP check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to see which site was requested.

Comment: ^repairs-([^\.]+)/(.*)/?$

Comment: @Marc B - Apologies, I should have mentioned this earlier. All the sites are unfortunately remaining under one domain name, otherwise your solution would have worked perfectly.